# What to consider before going from team lead to senior position?

Tags: job-offer, job-change

I'm currently a software engineering team lead with 10 people working in my team. I've been working here for three years.

I have an offer for a senior position in other company, which is not team lead, but has better financial offer and I would have the opportunity to learn and use more advanced technologies than at my current job. Technologies that I know for fact wouldn't be able to use at my current job.

I have good relationship with management at my current company and I do my job well. Therefore I'm not sure what are all of the aspects I could consider in order to make sure the change would be a wise idea.

What would you advise in this situation? Would it be considered a downgrade to go from team lead position to a senior one, despite the pay increase and better technological stack? What are the key things I should consider before I make my decision?

Comment: Why do you think it is a downgrade?

Comment: Essential reading: mipsytipsy's [The Engineer/Manager Pendulum](https://charity.wtf/2017/05/11/the-engineer-manager-pendulum/)

Answer (score 6):

I think the key to the decision is based on: Is this in line with your long term goals?

If you are looking towards management in the future, it may not make sense. But, if you are all about the cash and enjoying tech, that might be a great opportunity.

As far as the new job having a better tech stack, that will always be the case in a short time. So, long term, I don’t think that is a factor.

Many people would consider it a downgrade, but why care more about their opinion than your happiness or goals?

Comment: Seeing as team lead is a position many companies don't officially have (although many of those unofficially do) I wouldn't worry about it causing any problems if he wants to go into management later.

Answer (score 1):

Having done it, the main thing to remember is that you're going from a first among equals situation with the other senior engineers to being just one amoung equals.  You'll no longer be assigning work, and won't be able to tell juniors to do tasks that aren't worth your time (but are worth theirs).  You no longer get the last work on architecture decisions (although if you were using that authority much you probably weren't doing a good job as lead, as its generally better to build consensus).  Especially as the new guy, you'll have to step back, gauge the team, and pick your points to fight on.  Especially in the beginning as you need to earn respect.